# NotImplementedException on android

Tags: android

is there something similar to the NotImplementedException on the android platform?

thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you should use [UnsupportedOperationException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

Comment: It's great to know that Java has an Exception like this "built-in."  When I was doing web development, I used org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException but it's not like I'm gong to pull Commons Lang into into an Android project just for that exception. :)

Comment: Please correct the link, it is not available anymore.